# How to update Properties of Uploaded Documents on Sharepoint using Web Services?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to Update/Edit Properties of Uploaded Document on Sharepoint 2007.

My code:

```
 Lists listService = new Lists();
 listService.PreAuthenticate = true;
 listService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);
 listService.Url = "http://myserver/SiteName/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

 string strBatch =

                   "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'> "
                   + " <Field Name='ID'>3</Field> "
                   + " <Field Name='Name'>Preeti</Field> "                 
                   + " </Method> ";

 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
 System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
 elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");

elBatch.SetAttributeNode("UserName", "Preeti");
elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
XmlNode ndReturn = listService.UpdateListItems(ListName, elBatch);

MessageBox.Show(ndReturn.OuterXml);
```

**Refering** [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx).

**Getting Error: "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following  solution is provided from: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/File_Shunter.aspx

Note however, as mentioned in the other answer, the INTERNAL name of the field IS required.

**Web.Config Keys**

If you choose to, with the following added to the Web.config for your application (for this example only, alternatively you could simply include the required values [Server, Document Library, User, Domain, Password, etc.] in your code):

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>

<add key="SharePointServer" value=http://SP Portal/Site/>
<add key="DocLibrary" value="Doclib"/>
<add key="User" value="User"/>
<add key="Domain" value="Domain"/>
<add key="Pwd" value="Pwd"/>
<add key="GlobalSharedPath" value="D:\"/>
</appSettings>
```

**Code:**

```
Public Function WSSUpdateFile(ByVal sFileName As String, ByVal sSiteDoc As String, ByVal sTestCol As String) As String

        Dim sUser As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("User")
        Dim sPwd As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Pwd")
        Dim sDomain As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Domain")
        Dim sFileIDinList As String
        Dim strBatch As String = ""
        sSiteDoc = Replace(sSiteDoc, "%20", " ")
        sSiteDoc = Replace(sSiteDoc, "\", "/")
        Dim sFinalFilePath As String
        Dim sSPURL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SharePointServer")
        Dim sDocLib As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DocLibrary")
        Try
            Dim netAccess As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUser, sPwd, sDomain)
            Dim listService As New SPLists.Lists
            listService.Url = sSPURL & "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
            listService.Credentials = netAccess
            sFileIDinList = sGetID(listService.Url, sDocLib, sFileName)
            If sFileIDinList <> "" Then
                sFinalFilePath = sSPURL & "/" & sDocLib & "/" & sFileName
                'Now we have FileID so update the list
                strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" + _
                    "<Field Name = 'ID'>" & sFileIDinList & "</Field>" + _
                    "<Field Name = 'FileRef'>" & sFinalFilePath & "</Field>" + _
                    "<Field Name = 'TestCol'>" & sTestCol & "</Field>" + _
                    "</Method>"
                Dim xmlDoc = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
                Dim elBatch As System.Xml.XmlElement = xmlDoc.createelement("Batch")
                elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch
                Dim ndreturn As System.Xml.XmlNode = listService.UpdateListItems(sDocLib, elBatch)
            End If
            Return "TRUE"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function

Private Function sGetID(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal sListGUID As String, ByVal sFileName As String) As String
        Dim sUser As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("User")
        Dim sPwd As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Pwd")
        Dim sDomain As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Domain")
        Dim netAccess As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUser, sPwd, sDomain)
        Dim L As New SPLists.Lists
        L.Credentials = netAccess
        L.Url = sURL
        Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        Dim query As XmlNode = xmldoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "")
        query.InnerXml = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified'  Ascending='False'></FieldRef></OrderBy>"""
        Try
            Dim caml As XmlNode = L.GetListItems(sListGUID, Nothing, query, Nothing, "1", Nothing)
            Dim id As String = caml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(1).Attributes("ows_ID").Value
            Return id
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are using the internal names of the fields.

> To get the internal name of the field, open the "New" form and click "View Source" from context menu (right click any where in the "New" form page to open the context menu). You will see the fields along with their internal names near the end of the source file.

looking at the code:

```
string strBatch =

               "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'> "
               + " <Field Name='ID'>3</Field> "
               + " <Field Name='Name'>Preeti</Field> "                 
               + " </Method> ";
```

...

```
elBatch.SetAttributeNode("UserName", "Preeti");
```

are these actually two separate properties in sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **U2UCamlCreator** tool, to test your sharepoint queries.
This tool will help you to build batches to update sharepoint fields and many other features.